# How to clear all WebView stored information?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an Android browser and I have the option to clear cache, storage, cookies, etc.

The code looks like this:

```
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearFormData();
webView.clearHistory();
webView.clearSslPreferences();
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
```

And this seems to work on all my tests but when I go to google.com my old searches are still there. What am I not clearing?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same like `removeAllCookies`, but can you try `CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();`?

Comment: Found the solution `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();`

Comment: @casolorz please have a look at my answer

Comment: I have no issues with `deleteAllData()` and have never had a crash report from that on crashlytics with hundreds of thousands of the users using this app.

Comment: Hi! What's the purpose of calling
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
? according to documentation 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#flush()
it's not related to clearing cookies...

Comment: I don't remember, I think I copied this code from somewhere else. I guess the idea might be that this makes sure to save the store to disk while blocking access to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got a `root-access` granted device and found that calling `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();` and similar codes doesn't clear the `cache` created by the `WebView` at `applicationDatadir/app_webview`.

Also, that codes sometimes causes fatal errors like `A/libc: Send stop signal to pid:16145 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)`

*And it's (the cache) not so small in size.*

To achieve that you can use this following code snippet :

```
public static void clearWebViewCachesCustom(Context context) {
    try {
        String dataDir = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
        new File(dataDir + "/app_webview/").delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!MainActivity.deBugTest) Crashlytics.logException(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getSuppressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need all these tricks, `getContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir` is the documented way to get it.

Comment: On the other hand, you must delete all files and subfolders of `app_webview`; luckily, in Kotlin you have `File.deleteRecursively()`